# Fatal Exception AsyncTask #1

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I used json parsing to connect my php chatbot with android. The code works when I have an editText for text inputs. But when I implemented speech recognition for voice to text input my app suddenly stops. I get the following error.

```
04-18 00:25:11.928: E/AndroidRuntime(21316): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
04-18 00:25:11.928: E/AndroidRuntime(21316): Process: com.chatbot.mavis, PID: 21316
04-18 00:25:11.928: E/AndroidRuntime(21316): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
04-18 00:25:11.928: E/AndroidRuntime(21316): at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
04-18 00:25:11.928: E/AndroidRuntime(21316): at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
04-18 00:25:11.928: E/AndroidRuntime(21316): at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
04-18 00:25:11.928: E/AndroidRuntime(21316): at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
04-18 00:25:11.928: E/AndroidRuntime(21316): at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
04-18 00:25:11.928: E/AndroidRuntime(21316): at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker

(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
04-18 00:25:11.928: E/AndroidRuntime(21316):at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run

(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
04-18 00:25:11.928: E/AndroidRuntime(21316):at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
04-18 00:25:11.928: E/AndroidRuntime(21316):Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-18 00:25:11.928: E/AndroidRuntime(21316):at libcore.net.UriCodec.encode(UriCodec.java:132)
04-18 00:25:11.928: E/AndroidRuntime(21316):at java.net.URLEncoder.encode(URLEncoder.java:57)
04-18 00:25:11.928: E/AndroidRuntime(21316):at com.chatbot.mavis.Speech$GetBotResponse.doInBackground(Speech.java:182)
04-18 00:25:11.928: E/AndroidRuntime(21316):at com.chatbot.mavis.Speech$GetBotResponse.doInBackground(Speech.java:1)
04-18 00:25:11.928: E/AndroidRuntime(21316):at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
04-18 00:25:11.928: E/AndroidRuntime(21316):at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
04-18 00:25:11.928: E/AndroidRuntime(21316):... 4 more
```

And here is my code:

```
package com.chatbot.mavis;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.ActionBar.LayoutParams;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.RecognizerIntent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewTreeObserver;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ScrollView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
@SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
public class Speech extends Activity {

protected static final int Result_speech = 1;
String usertext;
String ask;
String str_botsay, str_convo_id;
String str_usersay;
TextView tvbt, tvut;
LinearLayout finlins;

LinearLayout ll1, ll2;
ImageView ui, bi;

String TAG_USERSAY = "usersay";
String TAG_BOTSAY = "botsay";
String TAG_CONVO_ID = "convo_id";

JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_speech);

    finlins = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lins);
    final ScrollView scvs = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.svs);
    final Button btns = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1s);

    btns.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            ui = new ImageView(v.getContext());
            bi = new ImageView(v.getContext());

            tvut = new TextView(v.getContext());
            tvbt = new TextView(v.getContext());

            Intent intent = new Intent(
                    RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
                    RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, "en-US");

            try {
                startActivityForResult(intent, Result_speech);
                tvut.setText("");
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                Toast t = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Your device does not support speech to text",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                t.show();

            }

        }
    });

    scvs.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
            new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                public void onGlobalLayout() {
                    scvs.post(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            scvs.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
}


@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
@SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (requestCode) {
    case Result_speech: {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {

            ArrayList<String> text = data
                    .getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);

            ll1 = new LinearLayout(Speech.this);
            ll2 = new LinearLayout(Speech.this);

            final LayoutParams lparams = new LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            final LayoutParams lparams2 = new LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

            ll1.setLayoutParams(lparams);
            ll1.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

            ll2.setLayoutParams(lparams);
            ll2.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

            finlins.addView(ll1);
            finlins.addView(ll2);

            ui.setLayoutParams(lparams2);
            bi.setLayoutParams(lparams2);

            tvut.setLayoutParams(lparams);
            tvbt.setLayoutParams(lparams);

            ll1.addView(ui);
            ll1.addView(tvut);
            ll2.addView(bi);
            ll2.addView(tvbt);

            tvut.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            tvut.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.user_bubble);
            tvbt.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            tvbt.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bot_bubble);

            ll1.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 5);

            ll2.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 35);

            //new GetBotResponse().execute();

            ui.setImageResource(R.drawable.user);
            ui.setPadding(0, 0, 25, 0);

            bi.setImageResource(R.drawable.bot);
            bi.setPadding(0, 0, 25, 0);

            usertext = text.get(0);
            tvut.setText(usertext);
        }
                    new GetBotResponse().execute();
        break;
    }

    }
}

private class GetBotResponse extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            ask = URLEncoder.encode(usertext, "UTF-8");
            Log.d("TEST", ask);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String url = "http://192.168.1.3/programo/chatbot/conversation_start.php?format=json&say="
                + ask;
        String URL = url.toString();
        JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrlByGet(URL);
        try {

            String str_usersay = json.getString(TAG_USERSAY);

            Log.i("TAG_usersay", str_usersay);
            str_botsay = json.getString(TAG_BOTSAY);

            Log.i("TAG_botsay", str_botsay);
            str_convo_id = json.getString(TAG_CONVO_ID);

            Log.i("TAG_convo_id", str_convo_id);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        tvbt.setText(str_botsay);

    }

}

}
```

Comment: please indicate line 180 @ `speech`

Comment: Look: `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException` something you're using is assigned to `NULL`. Check it out.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't get your answer @shayanpourvatan

Comment: you call `execute` before you set the value of `usertext`...

Comment: line 180 @ speech is `ask = URLEncoder.encode(usertext, "UTF-8");`, as you get `NPE` on this line so `usertext` is null, check that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `usertext` is `null` when you call `URLEncoder.encode` in `doInBackground`.

In `onActivityResult`, you *first* start your task and *then* set a value for `usertext`. That's not going to work, as the task may have already started running on the separate thread from `AsyncTask`. You probably want to move that `new GetBotResponse().execute();` line down just after `tvut.setText(usertext);`.

Either way, it would probably be better if you didn't rely so heavily on shared variables. In its current state, this is very susceptible for concurrency issues, for example when the user clicks rapidly multiple times in a row. This would cause multiple tasks to run concurrently, trying to read and write to the same variables and possibly producing inconsistent results.

`GetBotResponse` only needs `usertext` as input and produces `str_usersay`, `str_botsay` and `str_convo_id` as outputs. You could make `usertext` a `final` field of `GetBotResponse` and pass the value in its constructor. You could also make a wrapper class for those three strings and have the task return an instance which you then use in `onPostExecute`.

That way, you can get rid of those shared variables and don't have to lose sleep over nasty concurrency problems later on. You can still use some shared variables in `onPostExecute` to work with the UI (e.g. accessing `tvbt`), but you won't run into trouble there: at that point you're back on the GUI thread. ;-)

Comment: Tried, moved new GetBotResponse().execute(); right before the break; I still get those errors but in the logcat I can see the response from the bot.

Comment: @Ishwor You still get an NPE on the same line? That shouldn't be possible. Could you update the question with your updated code and error(s)?

Comment: @Ishwor Hmm, you moved it outside of the `if` block. It still needs to stay in that `if` block, but simply at the end of it (right after `tvut.setText(usertext);`). Although I'm not sure if that'll fix anything.

Comment: I moved it after tvut.setText(). It worked once, the app didn't crash. When I restarted the app and tried it, the app crashed like before.

Comment: It worked. I was executing the getBotRespose() twice, so it was crashing. Now it works. Thank you everyone for the response.

Comment: @Ishwor That would explain it, yes. You may want to have a look at the rest of my answer on how to improve your code and prevent such concurrency issues (due to two `GetBotResponse`s working on the same shared variables). ;-)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like `usertext` is null, you are only initializing it at `onActivityResult`